Rclone Python error when computing Hashes: ValueError
I am using Rclone_python (https://pypi.org/project/rclone-python/) to create some basic backup scripts for my server.
On one of my scripts, with rclone set up and properly configured on both client and server, there were issues with only the server running this. rclone configurations are both valid, and the same, using the same access keys and everything. rclone works on the server with the configuration, just isn't working in python.
The error I am receiving is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/rclone-backup-filechecker-python/main.py", line 145, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/rclone-backup-filechecker-python/main.py", line 43, in main
    dict_of_remote = get_hashes_from_files_remote(remote_path)
  File "/root/rclone-backup-filechecker-python/main.py", line 53, in get_hashes_from_files_remote
    result = rclone.hash(HashTypes.md5, remote_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclone_python/rclone.py", line 24, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclone_python/rclone.py", line 507, in hash
    value, key = l.split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My code is on: https://gitlab.atfdev.co.uk/alicethefemme/rclone-backup-filechecker-python if it helps to identify an error.
Upon further inspection, the rlcone.py file from the package is having the error.
value, key = l.split()
This was working prior to this, and upon tracking the variable that it wants to split, the errors aren't always consistent, with some files on my remote raising errors only occasionally. Any idea why this could be?

Obviously, how many items l.split() will split l into depends on the value of l. Only if there are 2 items, that line will raise no exception.

@mkrieger1 There should be only 2 items, and from the code in the package that I can see, there are only two items, however it is still randomly throwing this error. The package code is available here.

@klaus-d the library seemed to handle them all with 2 spaces. I changed it to split on those 2 spaces, and the error was still thrown. Might add in a .replace("  ", " ") (2 spaces into one), so anything with two is uniform, and then see if that helps.

Figured out the issue with the package being used. It was doing a split, which didn't take into account some directories using spaces in their names. Adding a maxsplit=1 into the code ensures that it is just the hash and the filename returned from this code. Will make a PR on GitHub for it. Thanks for the help!!
